I am Trying to create a service using SC Utility..using srvany.exe utility using sc create pythonservice bin path = c:/programfiles/tools/srvany.exe
I am Trying to create a PYTHON  service which is in virtual environment using SC Utility..using srvany.exe utility using  sc create pythonservice bin path = c:/programfiles/tools/srvany.exe
In Registry Editor added a key parameters
With strings
APP Directory
C:python/project/
APP PATH:
C:PYTHON/python.exe
APP PARAMETERS:
C:python/project/venv/scripts/activate/ C:PYTHON/python.exe core.py
Service is running but python  is not running not generating any logs ..
How to fix this
I am Trying to create a PYTHON  service which is in virtual environment using SC Utility..using srvany.exe utility using  sc create pythonservice bin path = c:/programfiles/tools/srvany.exe
In Registry Editor added a key parameters
With strings
APP Directory
C:python/project/
APP PATH:
C:PYTHON/python.exe
APP PARAMETERS:
C:python/project/venv/scripts/activate/ C:PYTHON/python.exe core.py
Service is running but python  is not running not generating any logs ..
How to fix this
